# BIND9, redirect specific DNS Request to different DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, dns-zone

I have a DNS server using BIND9 on Ubuntu 18.04 server, It acts as caching DNS server as well as local resolver for local network IPs.

This server forwards to Google DNS `8.8.8.8`, `8.8.4.4`.

I was wondering if it's possible to forward specific DNS request let's say `www.foo.bar` to another DNS server say `1.1.1.1` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `type forward` zone:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
        type forward;
        forwarders { 192.168.1.2; 192.168.1.254; };
};

zone "1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type forward;
        forwarders { 192.168.1.2; 192.168.1.254; };
};
```

http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch7/zone.html#type

Comment: The URL is the zone name ?

Comment: You asked for redirecting "specific DNS request". You didn't ask for "URL". And, that is impossible to resolve names based on anything beyond the sole domain name (port number, path and so on). Or I don't understand what do you mean by this comment.

Comment: Allow me to rephrase, the Domain which I am trying to resolve must be the zone name?

Comment: If you want to do this with BIND, it seems yes, the only way to "replace" one hostname resolution is to configure it as if it is a distinct zone. Other servers could do other way, for example, `dnsmasq` simply reads local `hosts` and serves them, so for it you'll only need to add another entry into `hosts `file.